# how to calculate geographical coordinates / which geo system is this?

Tags: geospatial, coordinate-systems, geocode, gis

I have a pair of geo coordinates I don't understand. Does anybody know this coordinate system and how to translate them to longitude and latitude in degrees?

Long. 7662.251 West, Lat. 9144.590 North
Has to be a position in Honduras (13- 16°N and 83-89° W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to investigate the source of the data, files, print outs, local gandolphs etc. Even if someone can find something with a stab in the dark it's likely to be wrong in some tiny detail. Where did the pair of coordinates come from? A text file? An email? Were there any auxiliary files?  With the same file name, but different extension?  In the same folder?  Attached to the email? Who gave it to you? What sort of computer do they use? Are they alive?  Etc.

There's simply not enough information in this question to answer it - tell us at least how you know that they are "geo coordinates" - how do you know that they must be in the Honduras?

Unfortunately this level of cultural metadata is quite often about the best we have. As a massive stab in the dark they might be projected coordinates in km, rather than metres - but they could be in feet - or anything, there's really only educated guesses that can improve on this as it stands.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, the coordinates are from a official expertise, delivered by a UN organization. The positions are in Honduras since the expertise is about installations in this country. I will check if I can find more details

Comment: there's usually something so be assured that any effort you put into finding clues is worth it - it's the best route (unfortunately we live in a systematic-metadata poor and context-assumptive rich environment)

Answer (score 1):

If it's not one of the common ones, such as UTM, have a search on the epsg registry for coordinate systems for Honduras:

http://www.epsg-registry.org/

and see if any work out. Would be a lot easier if you have any more coordinate pairs that are also in Honduras, because then we can work out an approximate scale.

I'll have a play and see if one of the UTM zones works out...

Comment: Its not UTM Zone 16N - Honduras is 250000 to 930000 in E-W coords, and 1400000 to 1700000 in N-S.